# doubling / paralleling in home electric

Tags: electrical

I have a 40 amp circuit.  Can I use 2x10AWG wire for each conductor instead of 1x8AWG?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel My guess is "Spool of 10 AWG wire lying around"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### No

The reason (aside from "code says you can't") is that if somehow one of the two conductors breaks or (more typically) disconnects at one end, instead of a dead circuit (annoying but safe), you have an overloaded wire **that can set your house on fire under normal load without ever tripping a breaker.**

Comment: It is under 1/0 AWG and less than 3 paralleled conductors. Don't even consider it unless you can meet those two requirements. The NEC has more conditions. But these are the reason I say no.

Comment: If one of the two conductors breaks or becomes disconnected it will **not** be safe. It will still be live as the other end is still connected.

Answer (score 1):

Hell no. Not least it violates the "All related conductors must be in the same cable or conduit" rule, causing imbalance/eddy current problems under *normal* conditions, plus the safety factor manassehkatz discusses.

However, if you *really* want to, and are willing to run some 3" conduit...

- You must increase the conductor size to 1/0 AWG as a bare minimum, and realistically nobody does this until they're above 4/0, so you won't find a 1/0-sized...
- specialized distribution panel **specifically designed for paralleling** on the supply side, and that type of equipment generally starts in the $1000 price range and 300A+.
- You must follow all the other rules for paralleling.
- You must get the AHJ to sign off on this, even though he's going to reject it out of general crazy-factor.
- However, you can still feed the $1000 distro panel from a 40A breaker.

Comment: thanks.  the conductors are in the same cable btw.

Comment: @WalrustheCat where did you get a 4-conductor #10 cable? I have never seen one of those.

Comment: Estonia ... :-(